# How to geocode using Google API Key in R ggmap as of 2019

Tags: r, geocoding, google-geocoder, ggmap, api-key

I am trying to use ggmap to geocode. Previously I used the source="dsk" argument in geocode() but apparently Data Science Toolkit is not providing geocoding services anymore.

I am looking for alternatives to this issue. I do not want to provide billing data to get an API key for google as I am using this in business and am not going to be held liable for fees incurred for my work.

Is there an alternate solution to geocode a few thousand addresses for free or is there a a way to get around the API Key issue using Google APIs.

Any tips or code workarounds that could help would be great.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this link [here](https://smartystreets.com/articles/is-there-a-geocoding-api-as-good-as-google)?

Note: it is written by SmartyStreets, a geocoding API, so it is biased. But it does compare and contrast some alternatives with their tradeoffs:

•Google
•TAMU
•Loqate
•Geocodio
•SmartyStreets

Also worth noting ([link](https://cengel.github.io/rspatial/5_Geocoding.nb.html))